# How to calculate piecewise linear slopes

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, data-munging

This may be a coding syntax question, but I would like this fine community of experts to weight in if you have the time.  I would like to calculate the slopes and intercepts of each segment in a piecewise linear regression to the first order.

This is a sample of my formula:

```
formula2 = 'pure_premium ~ eff_year_2010 + eff_year_2011 + eff_year_2012 + eff_year_2013 + eff_year_2014 + eff_year_2015 + \
            eff_year_2016 + eff_year_2017 + eff_year_2018 + rba_model + \
            + bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree = 1, knots = [55])   \
            + bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree = 1, knots = [25]) \
            + bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree = 1, knots = [32]) + yrs_owned_model  \
            + cm_ded_model  - 1'
```

So, as you can see from above, driver age, vehicle age and length in fee have one knot placed at 55 years of age, 25 years of age and 32 feet respectively.

I'll take driver age as an example.

According to this post, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/standard-error-of-slopes-in-piecewise-linear-regression-with-known-breakpoints, the coefficient give on the first segment (driver ages under 55) accounts for the slope, in this case 1.263.  The slope for drivers age above 55 should be the slope of the first + the slope the parameters are showing which is .299 therefore, the slope should 1.263+.299 which is 1.562.

1. Am calculating this correctly?
2. Is there a way to code this?  Example data frame below.

```py
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'variable': ['driver_age_model', 'driver_age_model', 'driver_age_model']
         , 'level': [54,55,56]
         , 'pricing_model_2_coefficient': [1.263361, 1.263361, .299176]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

df1

expectationion = {'variable': ['driver_age_model', 'driver_age_model', 'driver_age_model']
        , 'level': [54,55,56]
        , 'pricing_model_2_coefficient': [1.263361, 1.263361, .299176]
        , 'actual_slope': [1.26331, 1.26331, 1.5625]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(expection)

df2
```